# focus to text box

Tags: c#

I created a form with a label, textbox and a button. In the form load event I called the focus() function for the textbox. But when I run my code the cursor is not coming to textbox. I need the cursor to go to text box as soon as the form is loaded. How to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you simply need to make sure a certain control gets focus when you first load a form, then change the `TabOrder` properties of all your controls (in the Designer) so that the control in question is '0', and the other elements are going up from there, '1', '2', etc.

If you need to dynamically select a different control when you show a form depending on some condition, then use the following code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // You need to show the form otherwise setting focus does nothing 
    // (there are no controls to set focus to yet!)
    this.Show()
    if (someCondition == true)
        control.Focus();
    else
        control2.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Focus' can be set on the Form Shown event.

Comment: +1: set correct tab order of controls and let the framework do the job.

Comment: They might want a specific tab order but may not want to start with the 0 tab order property.

Comment: I agree with both @Monoxide and @Fredrik that this is the best method. Setting focus to a control manually is more natural when it is based on user interaction (rather than form load).

Comment: As long as you want consistant results, it doesn't matter where your tab order STARTS, it's a circle after all. If you want different starting places depending on some conditional, then go with some other solution, but in 90% of cases, this is the right way to do it.

Comment: @monoxide: not necessary, most people will expect the first focused element to be at the top left control as (Western any way) read top to bottom, left to right.

Comment: That's nothing to do with my answer: I'm simply telling how to change what the first focused element is.

Comment: Obviously there is more than one way to do this. I guess its down to Vicky now to decide how they want to code it.

Answer (score 3):

Handle the `Shown` event instead. This code should work.

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Focus();
}
```

Comment: This suffers the same problem as the Activated solution in that if you are hiding/showing the same form it will always reset the focus. This may or may not be a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call Focus in the Load event. Call it in the Activate event. That would work

Comment: It will also lead to the text box receiving focus every time the form is activated, which might not be desirable.

Comment: So which one will be the better way? Activate event or setting TabOrder?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the TabIndex property of textbox to 0 if you always want the focus on textbox when form loads. (This property is always eventually set in the form.designer.cs. And you won't have to write any extra code in your form.cs.)